# SQL LEFT JOIN with LIKE clause to give one row only

Tags: sql, ms-access

I have 2 tables which I want to join and I would like to generate the same number of rows that table 1 has.

Table 1

```
+----------+------------+---------+-------+
| ENTRY_ID | ROUTE_NAME | STATION | BOUND |
+----------+------------+---------+-------+
|        1 |         1A |    ABCC |     1 |
|        2 |         2C |    CBDD |     1 |
|        3 |          5 |    AAAA |     2 |
|        4 |         1A |    EEEE |     1 |
|        5 |         2B |    ASFA |     2 |
|        6 |          5 |    DSAS |     1 |
|        7 |          3 |    QWEA |     2 |
|        8 |          4 |    ASDA |     1 |
+----------+------------+---------+-------+
```

Table 2

```
+------------+-------+---------+---------------+
| ROUTE_NAME | BOUND | STATION | STOP_SEQUENCE |
+------------+-------+---------+---------------+
|         1A |     1 |     AAA |             1 |  
|         1A |     1 |     ABC |             2 |
|         1A |     1 |     CDA |             3 |
|         1A |     2 |     ABC |             1 |
|         1A |     2 |     ADC |             2 |
|         1A |     2 |     ACA |             3 |
|         2C |     1 |     BBB |             1 |
|         2C |     1 |     AAA |             2 |
```

Repeated for other values

The code that I have used is :

```
SELECT t1.ENTRY_ID, t1.ROUTE_NAME, t1.STATION, t1.BOUND, MIN(t2.STOP_SEQUENCE)
FROM T1 
LEFT JOIN t2 ON 
(t1.STATION LIKE '*' & t2.STATION & '*') AND
(t1.BOUND = t2.BOUND) AND
(t1.ROUTE_NAME = t2.ROUTE_NAME)
GROUP BY t1.ENTRY_ID, t1.ROUTE_NAME, t1.STATION, t1.BOUND
```

;

The LIKE function is a must in this case. The code doesn't return the same number of rows that TABLE 1 has. Instead for those rows not matching the LIKE requirement, they are not available in the query results. How can I obtain all rows even if the LIKE function doesn't return anything? My expected result is

```
+----------+------------+---------+-------+---------------+
| ENTRY_ID | ROUTE_NAME | STATION | BOUND | STOP_SEQUENCE |
+----------+------------+---------+-------+---------------+
|        1 |         1A |    ABCC |     1 |             2 |
|        2 |         2C |    CBDD |     1 |          NULL |
```

For 8 rows of ENTRY_ID.

Many thanks!

Comment: Skip the LEFT JOIN and the GROUP BY, try a correlated subquery instead.

Comment: If you want all rows of table1 to exist in the result why do you filter them (by `LIKE`)?

Comment: Can you try to add additional parentheses around the `JOIN` conditions, like `LEFT JOIN t2 ON ( (t1.STATION LIKE '*' & t2.STATION & '*') AND
(t1.BOUND = t2.BOUND) AND
(t1.ROUTE_NAME = t2.ROUTE_NAME) )`?

Comment: My idea for STOP_SEQUENCE is that, if there are "no LIKE" then return NULL, if yes, then return the (minimum) corresponding STOP_SEQUENCE (like ENTRY_ID 1 in the result), if not, return NULL. With regard to the correlated subquery and JOIN condition, I am not sure how to perform it.

Comment: The issue is you have an improper key between table1 and table2 making this join pert near impossible.

Answer (score 0):

Try a correlated subquery instead:

```
SELECT t1.ENTRY_ID, t1.ROUTE_NAME, t1.STATION, t1.BOUND,
       (SELECT MIN(t2.STOP_SEQUENCE) FROM t2
        WHERE (t1.STATION LIKE '*' & t2.STATION & '*')
          AND (t1.BOUND = t2.BOUND)
          AND (t1.ROUTE_NAME = t2.ROUTE_NAME)) as STOP_SEQUENCE 
FROM T1
```